# see value according to the array

Tags: laravel

I do a select and get several results in array but I need to get the correct value for each step and set up a condition.

```
    $step = DB::table('records')->where('id_user',$userId)->get();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($step); $i++)
    {
        echo $step[$i]->id_step;
    }
```

Id_step returns me values for each step where on the blade I need to get and see if id_step = 1 is true id_step = 2 is true.
This for is returning me only one value and it has 3 records in the table.

Comment: sorry, not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, can you perhaps reword what you are trying to achieve or some other pseudo code perhaps

Comment: $step brings me several records within [] I need to see all the values to use in a condition in the view.

Comment: okay, but i am still not sure what you are having trouble with .. values are fields, what you have is a collection of objects and those objects have properties that are the fields of the table, so you just want the field named `id_step` from these?

Comment: Yes @iagbox I receive several records where the id_step is equal to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 I want to have access to the records as follows.

If id_step ('1') = true and id_step ('2') = true ...                                                              I want to see if there is an id_step in the mentioned value in the selection.

Comment: sorry, i dont know what this "1 is true" or `2 = true` part is all about

Comment: can I consult the values of the object as desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working insert in view this code.

```
@for($i = 0; $i < count($step); $i++)
@if($step[$i]->id_step == 2)
                working
@else
                not working
@endif
@endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. After a select you get an instance of Eloquent\Collection
Not an array.
So that said to loop do this:

```
$steps = DB::table('records')->where('id_user',$userId)->get();

foreach($steps as $row) {
    echo $row;
}
```

Since you are familiar with arrays do this:

```
$steps->toArray();
```

Now your result is an array

Comment: this foreach only brings me the [0] I need to have access to all records that the $steps brings.